# Add Total to last row in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

DF<-

```
Date        Type1     Type2    Type%      Batch1        Batch2      Batch%
2021-01-10  5000      100      20.00%     3000          1500        50.00%
2021-01-10  5000      100      20.00%     3000          1500        50.00%
```

I Need to add a `Total` column as last row where I have sum of `Type1`, `Type2`, `Batch1` and `Batch2` along with percentage for `Type%` and `Batch%`

Required Output:

```
Date        Type1     Type2    Type%      Batch1        Batch2      Batch%
2021-01-10  5000      1000     20.00%     3000          1500        50.00%
2021-01-10  5000      100      2.00%      3000          1500        50.00%
Total       10,000    1,100    11.00%     6000          3000        50.00%
```

I have tried the following code, which worked for `sum` not sure about percentage.

```
sum_vector <- colSums(DF[,c(2,3,5,6)], na.rm = TRUE)
last_row <- vector()
last_row[1] <- "Total"
last_row[c(2,3,5,6)] <- sum_vector
last_row[4]<-(last_row[c(3)]/last_row[c(2)])*100 #Not Working
out <- rbind(DF, c(last_row))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `adorn_totals`

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(stringr)
DF %>%
   adorn_totals() %>%
   mutate(across(ends_with('%'), ~ str_c(replace(., n(), 
     sprintf("%.2f", mean(readr::parse_number(.[-n()])))), "%")))
```

-output

```
#  Date Type1 Type2   Type% Batch1 Batch2  Batch%
# 2021-01-10  5000   100 20.00%%   3000   1500 50.00%%
# 2021-01-10  5000   100  2.00%%   3000   1500 50.00%%
#      Total 10000   200  11.00%   6000   3000  50.00%
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(Date = c("2021-01-10", "2021-01-10"), Type1 = c(5000L, 
5000L), Type2 = c(100L, 100L), `Type%` = c("20.00%", "2.00%"), 
    Batch1 = c(3000L, 3000L), Batch2 = c(1500L, 1500L), `Batch%` = c("50.00%", 
    "50.00%")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Got error message `Error in mutate(., across(ends_with("%"), ~str_c(replace(., n(), sprintf("%.2f",  : 
  could not find function "adorn_totals"`

Comment: @user9211845 I did added the `library(janitor)` in my post

Comment: @user9211845 if you don't have the package, do the `install.packages('janitor')` and load the package `library(janitor)`

Comment: @user9211845 sorry, it is not clear about the issue in your installation.  i use `R 4.0.3`

Comment: @user9211845 it is a very old version.  I would suggest to update your R version because most of the  updated packages may not work in that version

Comment: any `dplyr` or base R solution for this?

Comment: @user9211845 I am not sure whether the `dplyr` solutions work for your version of R